# Having a hard time to understand for loops and nested for loops

Tags: for-loop, nested-loops

So, I understand programming very well,... but recently I came across with for loops and especially the nested ones.. I simply can't understand. It simply won't enter in my head. Can anyone give me some tips on how to perceive these loops better (or... at all)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

A program describes a sequence of operations for the computer to perform.  Among those operations may be some subsequences that the computer should repeat multiple times.  Instead of literally repeating these subsequences the appropriate number of times in the program source code (which in many cases is impossible), you can use a construct that tells the computer that at the end of such a subsequence it should return or 'loop' back to the beginning of that subsequence.  These types of constructs are conventionally called "loops".

In some cases, a repeating subsequence of operations itself contains a subsequence of operations that should be repeated multiple times as part of performing the one iteration of the containing sequence.  That, too, can be represented via a loop construct.

---

**Example: algorithm for cleaning the windows in my house**

1. Get cleaning supplies from the closet
2. If there are no more dirty windows then stop.  Else,
3. Go to the next dirty window.

   1. Spray cleaner
   2. Wipe window
   3. If it's not clean enough then go back to step 3.1
4. Go back to step 2.

That has two loops: an outer one comprising every step except the first, and an inner one comprising steps 3.1 through 3.3.

---

Often, there is some kind of initialization or starting state that the must be reached before starting the loop.  In the example, I must have my cleaning supplies at hand before I can actually clean any windows, and I want to start at the first window.

In most interesting cases, you don't know in advance how many times the program will need to run through a given loop.  In the example, for instance, I might be able to predict the number of iterations of the outer loop as the number of windows in my house, but I cannot be certain how many iterations of the inner loop will be needed for any given window.  Looping constructs handle this by providing flexible conditions for loop termination.

On the other hand, *something* has to change from iteration to iteration, else the repetition will never stop.  In the simplest case, the thing that changes to trigger eventual break from the loop is (abstractly) the number of loop iterations that have been performed already.  Often, though, we want a more flexible measure of whether any more iterations are needed, such as "is the window clean enough yet?"

A C/Java-style `for` loop formalizes those three elements: initialization (getting the supplies), termination condition (are there any more dirty windows?), and update (go to the next window).  The initialization step is performed once, before the first iteration.  The termination condition is tested before each iteration (and the loop terminates if it evaluates to `false`), and the update step is performed after each iteration, before testing the termination condition for the next iteration.  When the loop terminates normally, the computer next executes the statement immediately after the loop body.

To continue the silly example:

```
for (
    int window_number = 0;
    window_number < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_WINDOWS;
    window_number = window_number + 1) {

    Window currentWindow = windows[window_number];

    do {

        cleaner.spray(currentWindow);
        cloth.wipe(currentWindow);

    } while (currentWindow.isDirty());

}
```

In this case I represented the inner loop with a different loop construct (`do { ... } while`) because it fits more naturally with the facts that there is no initialization step required, I don't need to test for termination before the first iteration, and the update step is performed within the body of the loop.  Since it wouldn't actually be harmful to test the termination condition before the first iteration, however, I can write the inner loop as a `for` loop, too.  I just leave the parts I don't need blank (but I *always* need the two semicolon separators):

```
for (
    int window_number = 0;
    window_number < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_WINDOWS;
    window_number = window_number + 1) {

    Window currentWindow = windows[window_number];

    for (
        /* no initialization */ ;
        currentWindow.isDirty();
        /* no (additional) update */) {

        cleaner.spray(currentWindow);
        cloth.wipe(currentWindow);

    }

}
```

And that's most of what you need to know about loops in general and `for` loops in particular.

Answer (score 1):

When we place one loop inside the body of another loop is called nested loop. And the outer loop will take control of the number of complete repetitions of the inner loop meaning the inner loop in the below example will run at least 10 times due to the condition a<10.

In the below example "Print B" will appear 200 times i.e. 20 * 10. The outer loop A will run inner loop B 10 times. And since inner loop B is configured to run 20 times the total number of times Print B will appear is 200.

```
// Loop: A
for(int a=0;a< 10;a++) {
    // Loop: B
    for(int b=1;b<20;b++) {
        System.out.println("Print B");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different types of for loops, but all behave similarly.

The basic idea of a for loop is that the code inside the for loop block will iterate for as long as the iterator is within a certain range.

i.e.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        int x = i;
    }
```

In the code here (C++) the iterator is i, and the code block is int x = i. This means that the code block will be executed from i = 0, to i = 9, each time setting x to i and then increasing the value of i by 1.

Here you can see another description: [C++ For Loops](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/#for)

And if you are working in Java: [Java For Loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm)

Nested for loops work the same way, the only difference is that for each iteration of the outer loop you iterate completely the inner loop.

i.e.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       for(int j = 0; j < 5; i++)
       {
         int x = j;
       }
    }
```

Here you see that each time you execute the code inside the first for loop, you will execute the code inside the inner for loop to completion, or until j equals 5. Then you iterate the outer loop and run it again.

Hope this helps.